# Arbitrary Precision Numbers, Google App Engine, Python, NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, arbitrary-precision

As an academic exercise, I am trying to achieve an arbitrary precision (call it AP) system in google app engine using python and the NDB storage. I know that there are AP libraries out there so we can skip that.

I am curious how one might store the numbers from an AP library in a way that they could be query-able with greater than, less than, and equal operators. Ideally, this could be done using a custom property class within the NDB model, but since the NDB model uses Python and Python does not support AP numbers natively, I am not sure this is possible. If you guys agree, then we can move on to talking about storage generally - SQL, MongoDB, NDB, etc.

As I understand them, AP systems often separate the AP number into coefficients (in an array?), an exponent, and a sign. If we stored these, is there a combination of filters on these fields that could achieve a greater than, less than, and equals operations? Is it even possible to store the coefficient if it is indeed stored as an array?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution. First off, I need to use the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) object, no AP library needed it sounds like. To store it, I could convert it to a string using one of the class's methods. For instance, [get a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.as_tuple) from it, and convert to a string. Then, I could store that string in a NDB Text[Property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types) and use an additional ComputedProperty to convert that string to Decimal.

However, I am not really sure how that ComputedProperty would be stored in NDB and if it would really be AP and thus useful to query against. [The docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed) say "The computed value is written to the Datastore so that it can be queried...". But is it stored as an actual decimal? Or an AP number?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sub-classed property: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/subclassprop

In your case, either as a string (then cast it back to a Decimal in your _from_base_type) or as two integers (an integer representing the whole number, and the dividing exponent to return the number (e.g. 0.123 as 123 and 3 as 123/10^3 == 0.123).

A ComputedProperty cannot store data types outside the normal ones.